# Problems compiling with enum value PORT1-7

Tags: c++

So I have this enum in a header file:

```
enum class ServoPort {PORT1 = 1, PORT2, PORT3, PORT4, PORT5, PORT6};
```

The trouble is that when I try to use it in the primary file (by doing `MyClass::ServoPort::PORT1`) I get a compile error:

```
exit status 1
expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

However, if I change the enum to be like so:

```
enum class ServoPort {PORT8 = 1, PORT9, PORT10, PORT11, PORT12, PORT13};
```

Then I do not get a compile error. ***What the heck?*** Can someone please shine some light on why this is happening?

---

- Board: UNO R3
- IDE: v1.8.5

Comment: Please add which Arduino board and IDE version.

Comment: If you are using an AVR based Arduino board it might be a conflict with the AVR header file pinsport.h.

Comment: @MikaelPatel done

Comment: Please see the file: arduino-xxx/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/portpins.h. If you really want to use these symbols you could undef them in your header file.

Comment: @MikaelPatel hmm, ok yeah I could see that being a problem if I was trying to do a `#define PORT2` or something, but in this case I'm creating an **enum** that has a a member of that name. It seems to me that shouldn't cause a conflict? I'm from a Java background so maybe I don't know what I'm talking about...

Comment: The defines are pre-processed symbols before compiling. Your definition gives an illegal syntax when replaced. `PORT1 = 1, PORT2`, becomes, `1 = 1, 2`.

Comment: @MikaelPatel I see, but shouldn't the preprocessor be smart enough to not do that?

Comment: Some reading: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309389/what-is-the-origin-of-the-c-preprocessor, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp.pdf

Comment: Should add that #define, #undef, #include, etc, are not part of C/C++. It is the tools cpp, c pre-processor, that handles them before handling the resulting file to the compiler, cc/gcc.